# Python: How can I turn a string into a url-safe string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, how can I turn this:

`This is a string!`

into this:

`this-is-a-string`

I would like the conversion to exclude all special characters and only accept letters and numbers, and replace spaces with `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically to encode a string to a URL safe value, you just need to run it through urllib's parser:

```
import urllib.parse
print(urllib.parse.quote(value))
```

However, you're asking for a custom transformation.  You can use some string built ins and the regular expression library to do that:

```
import re
print(re.sub("[^a-z0-9-]", "", value.lower().replace(" ", "-")))
```

If you want to allow more than `a-z`, `0-9`, and `-` as "valid", then you'll need to extend the regular expression.

Comment: Thank  , Wasn't aware of Re !

Answer (score 0):

You can use encodeURIComponent on which is in ES5 Lib.

```js
/**
 * Encodes a text string as a valid component of a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).
 * @param uriComponent A value representing an unencoded URI component.
 */
declare function encodeURIComponent(uriComponent: string | number | boolean): string;
```

Examples:

```js
// Encodes characters such as ?,=,/,&,:
console.log(`?x=${encodeURIComponent('test?')}`);
// Expected output: "?x=test%3F"

console.log(`?x=${encodeURIComponent('шеллы')}`);
// Expected output: "?x=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B"
```